# How to make restartable flatMapConcat?

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

I'm calling an API for each element of the stream, that returns a `Source`. Naturally, I use `flatMapConcat` to get a stream of responses for subsequent processing. Thing is, sometimes this API fails and a client needs to be recreated. Is there a way to do it without creating a client for each element of the stream? Here's the example code:

```
class Client {
  def makeRequest(id: Int): Source[String, NotUsed] = ???
}

object Hello extends App {
  implicit val system = ActorSystem()
  implicit val ec = system.dispatcher

  val client = new Client()

  Source(Seq(1, 2, 3, 4))
    .flatMapConcat(id => client.makeRequest(id)) // How to restart this?
    .runForeach(println(_))
}
```

UPD: This is what I ended up using:

```
flatMapMerge(10, { id =>
      RestartSource.onFailuresWithBackoff(1 second, 30 seconds, 0.1) { () =>
        val client = new Client()
        client.makeRequest(id)
      }
    })
```

Comment: Does it fail on creation? Or after processing some of the events? If some of the events were processed, do you want to reprocess them? That code does not compile at the moment, because you are missing an actor materializer. Please note that if you create endless amount of sources, you'll get out of memory exceptions. You need to think how to release those at some point.

Comment: I've updated the question with current solution, it creates a client for each request which is not *that* bad because these requests are fairly time consuming and creating a client doesn't really affect performance. But still, I'd like to be able to use the same client for all requests. The source could fail only after emitting some events and in that case I want to repeat the query.